# What information gathering should be done in order to collect why yum autoremove nmap* causes mariadb/npcd/httpd erased in RHEL 7.9 Clustering?

Tags: rhel

I need to collect information regarding why
`yum autoremove nmap*`
causes mariadb/httpd/npcd erased automatically?

It happen on RHEL 7.9 clustering node02. Kindly advised. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't have RHEL (or CentOS) but a quick search suggests you could try `rpm -q --whatrequires nmap`

Comment: start with: `yum history`  and `yum history info xx`. You'll have the list of affected packages which you might then provide in the question. Who knows? imagine there was a file named `nmap mariadb httpd npcd` (with spaces) in the directory?